# Tenserflow module is giving errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to import some modules but I get errors back. These are what I am trying to import and install:

```
%pip install pandas
%pip install numpy
%pip install requests
%pip install beautifulsoup4
%pip install tensorflow

import requests
import pandas
import numpy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tensorflow
```

after running the code, what I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 12
     10 import requests
     11 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
---> 12 import tensorflow
     13 import keras

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:41
     38 import six as _six
     39 import sys as _sys
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     44 # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at import.

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py:40
     31 import traceback
     33 # We aim to keep this file minimal and ideally remove completely.
     34 # If you are adding a new file with @tf_export decorators,
     35 # import it in modules_with_exports.py instead.
     36 
     37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
...
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

More information: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates
```

I am using python 3.9.13 - TensorFlow is 2.12.0, conda 23.3.1 and anaconda custom py29_1

Comment: have you already tried to downgrade the protobuf package as written in the error? `pip install protobuf==3.20.*`

Comment: I did, same issue persists. On top of that, I get this error on terminal after installation:

tensorflow 2.12.0 requires protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.3, but you have protobuf 3.20.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-metadata 1.13.1 requires protobuf<5,>=3.20.3, but you have protobuf 3.20.0 which is incompatible.
googleapis-common-protos 1.59.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.0 which is incompatible.
@vighub

Comment: Ok, so you can not have version 3.20.0, as written in your new error. What if you do `pip install protobuf==3.20.3` ? I see in your error log that is a valid version

Comment: I did that, now I am getting a new error:
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.

I looked into it, and this is what that click me link says: (in the new comment down here)@vighub

Comment: If a kernel crashes when using tensorflow, this is indicative of tensorflow having been incorrectly installed into the Python Environment. Re-installing the package would resolve the issue.

If this does not work, it is also possible other dependent packages could cause the package to fall over, in such cases, its best to start out with a new environment.

Finally, when using Conda environments, please avoid using pip to install packages, instead use conda install

Comment: Hi @Amin, There is some version mismatch issue with tensorflow and other packages in this environment. Could you please try again by creating new VirEnv in anaconda and try reinstalling TensorFlow using code `pip install tensorflow==2.12`. Some of the packages like `requests, numpy` are already integrated in the TensorFlow package and will get installed automatically with the TensorFlow package. So you need not to install these packages explicitly. Let us if the issue still persists.